# jQuery jplist checkbox default checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplist

I need helps.
How to add default a checkbox in jplist.
Example:

```
<input value="Anne Stokes" data-path="Anne Stokes"  type="checkbox">
```

I want this default selected

Answer (score 1):

can be done by adding checked attribute to input

```
<input value="Anne Stokes" data-path="Anne Stokes"  type="checkbox" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

> To make a checkbox checked by default, you simply give it the checked attribute
>
> > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

```
 <input value="Anne Stokes" data-path="Anne Stokes"  type="checkbox" checked>
```

**Sample Code Snippet:**

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose your interests</legend>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="coding" name="interest" value="coding" checked>
    <label for="coding">Coding</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="music" name="interest" value="music">
    <label for="music">Music</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```